# DB2 Max Timestamp of columns in the same record

Tags: database, view, db2, left-join

I have 3 tables A, B, C in DB2. They have one-one relationship.
A is the parent table and B, C are child tables.

Each of the tables have a timestamp column that tracks changes to the record. Lets say T1,T2,T3.

I want to write a view that gets all records in A, B, C per key (say ID column) so that i get one logical record from all three tables. I understand that i can use A left outer join with B and C. Along with the logical record with selected columns, i also want the max(T1,T2,T3). Its not max timestamp of a column across rows but within the same logical record.

I am not into writing queries, hence need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `GREATEST()` and `VALUE()` to change NULLs to arbitrary low timestamp:

```
SELECT a.id, 
GREATEST(
  VALUE( T1, TIMESTAMP  '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
  VALUE( T2, TIMESTAMP  '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),
  VALUE( T3, TIMESTAMP  '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
)     
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON a.id = c.id
```

Comment: Still the same null issue that i mentioned for the solution from Charles. I am kind of doing this max(COALESCE(T1, X), COALESCE(T2, X), COALESCE(T3, X)), where X is a 1970 TS. Does this make sense? or any shorter form available?

Comment: Pesky `NULL` is always spoiling the fun: Scalar functions will return `NULL` if any value passed is null.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is one record per ID in each table, then:

```
select a.id, max(a.T1, b.T2, c.T3)
from tblA A
      join tblB B on b.id = a.id
      join tblC C on c.id = a.id
```

Would give you what you ask for.  `MAX()` simply returns the maximum value in the given set.  It's up to you as to where that set comes from.

Without the use of a `GROUP BY`, `MAX()` only has the set of values from each row in the result set.

Comment: I need the left outer join, so tried this "select a.id, max(a.T1, b.T2, c.T3) from tblA A left outer join tblB B on b.id = a.id left outer join tblC C on c.id = a.id"...but if for a key if it exists in A, B but not in C then max timestamp gives null but i want max from A and B

Comment: Use `coalesce(c.t3, 0)` probably need the same on t2.   Might need to replace 0 with a valid timestamp.  '0001-01-01 00;01:00.0000'